# How to show that $e^{-x/2} x^{y-1} \leq 1$ for $x$ large enough and $y\geq 1$

Tags: limits, inequality

I am wondering how to show that $e^{-x/2} x^{y-1} \leq 1$ for $x$ large enough and $y\geq 1$

I thought I could try to solve for an $x$ s.t. $e^{\frac{x}{2}} > x^{y-1}$, but if I try to take logs to get rid of the $e$, I end up with a log of $x$.

Comment: You don't have to pinpoint exactly how large $x$ needs to be. It suffices to show, say, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{y-1}}{e^{x/2}} = 0$.

Comment: @angryavian Hmmm, So the idea is that since the limit goes to $0$ for $x$ large enough the ratio is $<\epsilon<1$, but the definition of limit? **Also**, if I use L'Hopital's rule (say $y-1$ times) than the numerator eventually becomes a constant while the denominator does not, so the denominator will go to $\infty$ and the limit goes to zero. is that correct?

Comment: $y$ need not be an integer, but I think you have the right idea.

Comment: @angryavian L'hopital will still work when $y$ not an integer though, right? Because I can differentiate $>y-1$ times so the $x$ goes to the denominator. **I guess I am wondering whether there is a cleaner way to show the limit goes to 0 besides L'Hopital**?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly apply your idea of L'Hospital because it would not give you a constant in the end if $y$ is not an integer. So you would need to use a squeeze as well.

Another method: note that $$e^{-x/2} x^{y-1}=e^{-x/2+(y-1)\ln x}$$
So all you have to do is prove that for $a,b\geq0$, $$\lim_{x\to \infty}(a\ln x-bx)=-\infty$$
Factor by $x$ and apply L'Hopital to see that $\ln x\over x$ tends to $0$ at infinity.

Comment: But with L'Hopital don't we eventually get two term in the denominator going to infinity, giving the result? So why would we need a squeeze?

Comment: If you squeeze the initial function between two others where $y$ is an integer, you can apply L'Hopital to these two.

Comment: I guess I am confused about why $y$ not an integer is a problem. L'Hopital doesn't require $y$ to be an integer, I don't thin?k. I am thinking of something like $y=1.5$ so $\frac{x^{.5}}{e^{x/2}}$, then take the derivative of top and bottom gives $\frac{1}{x^{.5}e^{x/2}}$, and then the denominator goes to infinity, and the limit to $0$.

Comment: @majmun Oh yes, in that sense it's fine. But you were saying that "in the end the derivative is a constant", THAT requires $y$ to be an integer.